# VueJs does not track changes on @input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue does not track changes on `customizableFormData` property while I change the input.

[image]

Simplified source code:

```
<template> 
    <input type="checkbox" @input="setFormField(form.name, 'does_attend', $event.target.checked)">
</template>
<script>
export default {

    data() {
        return {
            form: {}//it's set by AJAX on mounted event,
            customizableFormData: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setFormField(formName, inputName, value) {
            if(this.customizableFormData[formName] === undefined) {
                this.customizableFormData[formName] = {};
            }
            this.customizableFormData[formName][inputName] = value;
            console.log(this.customizableFormData); // shows correct data
            this.$forceUpdate();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you use vue 2 or vue 3 ? In vue 2, you need to use `set` to make added property reactive. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!